# Ios Add objects in a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

how can I add an object in an array by clicking a button 
I use this methode :

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{

[orderListe addObject:[[DataOrder alloc]initWithName:@"Michael" price:18 taille:@"junior" supplement:@"boeuf"]];

}
```

When I do that my application crash and say :

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DataOrder initWithName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8aa4fa0'
```

What can i do to simply add an object to an array ? 
Thank you

Comment: It is strange that the selector in your *code* `initWithName:price:taille:supplement:` does not match the selector `initWithName:` from the *error message*. Are you sure that you pasted the correct/complete code and error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course that you can add an object to an array. The exception is thrown because the method initWithName:price: ... is not implemented in the DataOrder class.

Answer (score 1):

The error your getting has to do with the DataOrder object. During it's initialization it ran into an error. You're sending it some value it isn't expecting.

Perhaps try and separate the line where you alloc the Data Order object and try to add it to the array?

```
 DataOrder *do = [[DataOrder alloc] initWithName....];
 [orderListe addObject: do];
```

this will let you see where you messed up?